# phpseclib include path not working as expected

Tags: php, phpseclib, vendor

I'm using phpseclib (3.0) installed via composer.

If I do the following, I get a class not found error for 'SFTP':

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

$sftp = new SFTP('ip here');
```

This file is in the same directory as 'vendor', so the path seems legit to me.

However, everything works as expected if I actually put my file inside of the 'vendor' folder and just include 'autoload.php', which obviously isn't ideal.

So the setup that actually works is when I have:

- vendor

  - myFileThatIncludesAutoload.php
  - 'phpseclib' directory

Any suggestions on why my first approach could be off?

Thanks

Comment: The namespace changed. Do `use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA; use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;`. The RSA API has also changed significantly. See https://phpseclib.com/ for more info. In fact, I'd say: if you're doing `use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA` you're doing it wrong. In phpseclib3 you should be doing `use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;`. phpseclib3 supports more than just RSA keys so limiting yourself to RSA is unnecessary.

Comment: If you wanted to use the phpseclib2 API with phpseclib3 you could install https://packagist.org/packages/phpseclib/phpseclib2_compat . The namespace change enables shims like that.